# nullreference glBindFramebufferEXT C#

Tags: c#, opengl, tao-framework

I'm trying to render to a texture using Tao.OpenGl. I get a mysterious NullReference on the following line:

```
    Gl.glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, out targetFrameBuffer);   <---NullReference
    Gl.glBindFramebufferEXT(Gl.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, targetFrameBuffer);
```

and also on the second line if i do this:

```
    //Gl.glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, out targetFrameBuffer);   
    Gl.glBindFramebufferEXT(Gl.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, targetFrameBuffer);   <---NullReference
```

The obvious candidate is 'targetFrameBuffer', but the debugger reports that 'targetFrameBuffer' is *not* NULL, and i've also used dummy values to be sure...

Anyone of you know what could be the problem?

**EDIT:**
After changing to OpenTK instead of Tao, it still complains on the same lines, although now it says "Unable to find an entry point named 'glGenFramebuffers' in DLL 'opengl32.dll'." instead. Perhaps my opengl32.dll is corrupt in some way?

Comment: Sure that the call is not in external code?

Comment: Do you have EXT_frambuffer_object?

Comment: @harold is right, check to see if your video card supports that extension and then use the LoadAllExtensions method (on Gl or GLExt, I believe) to load all supported extensions.

Comment: @harold Yup, Gl.IsExtensionSupported("EXT_framebuffer_object") returns true.

Comment: @ananthonline I can't find it? I Tried `Gl.Load("EXT_framebuffer_object")` and `GlExtensionLoader.LoadAllExtensions()`, the latter being obsolete, but none worked, or rather, it seems it works but i still get the NullReference. Stupid question maybe, but couldn't i somehow find out what object is null? I'm not sure where to look...

Comment: @FelixK. I'm not sure about anything :) What do you mean, that the openGl framework is somehow faulty?

Comment: It's possible, the Tao framework is essentially dead so bugs don't get fixed. You could look into OpenTK. I'm not too sure about pixel owenership rules, you could look into that as well (but I'd expect a different kind of exception from that).

Comment: @harold Thx for the tip! Installing... (And then a couple of hours rewriting it all for OpenTK ;)

Comment: @harold Whoa, that's a lot of rewriting... Every openGl call is different, and all the openGl constants are conveniently hidden from sight... Where are they???

Comment: You could probably do some smart search&replaces.. The constants are in enums in OpenTK, IntelliSense should make them appear automatically.

Comment: Haha, no this time it was NotSoIntelliSense(tm). Do you know how TexParameter works? Previously i had `GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_NEAREST)` but now OpenTK wants an int as the last parameter? What value should i put there to represent nearest/linear etc.?

Comment: BTW, the first one to answer with "Probably just a bug..." will be awarded a marked answer!

Comment: @mickey known problem in OpenTK, not sure why they don't change it. You can use `(int)GL.Enums.All.LINEAR`

Comment: @harold Big thanks! Another one (right about now you should mention the fact that you have a certain 'fee' for dumbasses like me), where do i find the handy GLu goodies, like gluPerspective? Do i really have to learn about the frustrum... :(

Comment: Ok so it was apparently fixed. `(int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest`

Comment: The plot thickens. Is the GL context that is created actually hardware accelerated or the software fallback?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11629/discussion-between-mickey-and-harold)